# How to change pointer size with python - windows

Tags: python, windows

I was wondering if there is any way to change the pointer size on windows with python.
I just want to make something where when you press a button it makes the pointer bigger or smaller, but I can't figure out how to change the pointer size.

Comment: Do you want to change the pointer size in a window/application that you have made?

Comment: No. I just want to change the window's pointer size. So like the regular windows pointer, not in a window/application.